# AngularJS: $scope.flags.loading For A Particular Section

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add the loading icon for a particular section of the page (**Note: Entire page SHOULD NOT have this**) while making an AJAX calls or on some events. I tried writing a directive and which makes that scope's flags.loading = true. But this didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: could you share what you have implemented with jsfiddle

Comment: Actually it isn't much. I wrote a directive and for it's scope, I added scope.flags.loading = true

Comment: @Abilash actually it's important that you show us the code since in a directive there are multiple places where you can place the code and that might be where the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have working example of directive changing parent scope's variable `loading` from value `no` to `yes`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('loadingDirective', function() {

    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {         
        scope.loading="yes";        
    };

    return {
        link: linkFn
    }

});

app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.loading = "no";    
});
```

Here you have also working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDKVC/2/).